# Select elements in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Given this code in HTML:

```html
<body>
    <pre class="typescript">
      <span class="classDecl">    
        <span class="statement">export</span> 
        <span class="keyword">class</span> 
        <span class="identifier">Sample</span> 
        <span id="open1">{</span>
        <span class="keyword">private</span> 
        <span class="marked">
          <span class="identifier">name</span>: 
          <span class="type">string</span>
        </span>;
        <span class="ctorDecl">
          <span class="keyword">constructor</span>
          <span id="open2">(</span>
          <span class="marked">
            <span class="identifier unused">name</span>: 
            <span class="type">string</span>
          </span>
          <span id="close2">)</span> 
          <span id="open3">{</span>
          <span class="keyword">this</span>.
          <span class="identifier">name</span> = 
          <span class="error">
            <span class="identifier">name1</span>
          </span>;
          <span id="close3">}</span>
        </span>
        <span class="methodDecl">
          <span class="identifier">greeting</span>
          <span id="open4">(</span>
          <span id="close4">)</span>: 
          <span class="type">string</span> 
          <span id="open5">{</span>
          <span class="statement">return</span> 
          <span class="stringliteral">"Hello "</span> + 
          <span class="keyword">this</span>.
          <span class="identifier">name</span>;
          <span id="close5">}</span>
        </span>
        <span id="close1">}</span>
      </span>
    </pre>
</body>
```

Im trying to select the :, ; , = and + symbols but I dont know how. (One is at line 8)

I tried googling but none of the answers worked.

Comment: in what language do you want to do it and for what purpose?

Comment: in css its for a homework where i have to highlight the syntax of a code

Comment: It is hard to read your code, but from what I can see your `+` are outside any sort of selector or html tag. So you cannot hope to target them with css alone. Are you able to change the markup? Otherwise you would have to do this dynamically with javascript which would be much more expensive.

Comment: i cant change anything and im only allowed to use css

Comment: This is working although I would not recommend it, it depends what you want to do with the selectors: https://jsfiddle.net/lharby/ducsag31/

Comment: the code changes every element into the color and not just onlythe symbols my prof wants

Comment: You have been  assigned a test in how to use *CSS selectors*. Search online what they are and how to use them. Please, don't (ab)use our voluntarily donated time to do your homework for you.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a homework assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Following solution works with 6 css classes, and some layered specificity

https://jsfiddle.net/tadpole/pthgxqny/1/

```
.classDecl{
  color: red;
}
.classDecl > span{
  color: black;
}
span.ctorDecl{
  color: red;
}
span.ctorDecl > span{
  color: black;
}
span.methodDecl{
  color: red;
}
span.methodDecl > span{
  color: black;
}
```